# How to distribute a file across presto cluster in kuebernetes

Tags: kubernetes, presto, kubernetes-pod, starburst

I'm new to Kubernetes. We have a presto (starburst) cluster deployed in Kubernetes and we are trying to implement SSL certificate for the presto cluster.

Based on the below URL, I have created a keystore (in my local machine) and have to populate this keystore path to 'http-server.https.keystore.path'

https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/security/internal-communication.html

However, this file has to be distributed across the cluster. If I enter the local path then Kubernetes is throwing 'file not found' error. Could you please let me know how to distribute this in presto cluster in kubernetes.

I have tried creating the keystore as secret and mounted this to a volume.

```
kubectl create secret generic presto-keystore --from-file=./keystore.jks
```

```
kind: Presto
metadata:
  name: stg-presto
spec:
  clusterDomain: cluster.local
  nameOverride: stg-presto
  additionalVolumes:
    - path: /jks
      volume:
      secret:
        secretName: presto-keystore
  additionalJvmConfigProperties: |
  image:
    name: xxxxx/presto
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    tag: 323-e.8-k8s-0.20
  prometheus:
    enabled: true
    additionalRules:
      - pattern: 'presto.execution<name=TaskManager><>FailedTasks.TotalCount'
        name: 'failed_tasks'
        type: COUNTER
  service:
    type: NodePort
    name: stg-presto
  memory:
    nodeMemoryHeadroom: 30Gi
    xmxToTotalMemoryRatio: 0.9
    heapHeadroomPerNodeRatio: 0.3
    queryMaxMemory: 1Pi
    queryMaxTotalMemoryPerNodePoolFraction: 0.333
  coordinator:
    cpuLimit: "5"
    cpuRequest: "5"
    memoryAllocation: "30Gi"
    image:
      pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    additionalProperties: |
      http-server.http.enabled=false
      node.internal-address-source=FQDN
      http-server.https.enabled=true
      http-server.https.port=8080
      http-server.https.keystore.path=/jks/keystore.jks
      http-server.https.keystore.key=xxxxxxx
      internal-communication.https.required=true
      internal-communication.https.keystore.path=/jks/keystore.jks
      internal-communication.https.keystore.key=xxxxxxx
```

Also tried creating config and mounted it as a volume. But still getting 'Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /jks/keystore.jks (No such file or directory)'.

Could you please let me know if am missing anything.

Thanks

Comment: As you are using Starburst's, the correct docs link is https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/security/internal-communication.html (i've updated it above too, for posterity).

Comment: Hi @PiotrFindeisen, I have tried the approach that Tarun has mentioned below

1. Created configMap
 kubectl create configmap presto-keystore --from-file=/cert/keystore.jks
2. Used below in the Presto yaml file
  additionalBootstrapScriptVolume:
      configMap:
        name: presto-keystore
3. Also, used properties for coordinator and workers in the same Presto yaml file.
  additionalProperties: |
      internal-communication.https.keystore.path=presto-keystore

But still am getting 'file not found' issue. Could you please advise if am missing anything. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create a secret or Configmap using your keystore and mount it as volume and then use the path in your files.

How to create and use configMap in k8s [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

How to configure a secret in k8s [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/)

You can use both in a similar fashion in your Custom Resource as in any other resource. I see an option of `additionalVolumes` and documentation associated with it [here](https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/kubernetes/presto_resource.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a secret in K8s and mount it within Presto deployment using `additionalVolumes` property.
Checkout documentation on `additionalVolumes` at https://docs.starburstdata.com/latest/kubernetes/presto_resource.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a secret from a file:

```
kubectl create secret generic cluster-keystore --from-file=./docker.cluster.jks
```

2. Add the secret in the "additionalVolumes" section in the yaml: (per Karol's URL above)

```
 additionalVolumes:
  - path: /jks
   volume:
    secret:
     secretName: "cluster-keystore"
```

3. Add the jks file to the coordinator "additionalProperties" section in your yaml:

```
  coordinator:
    cpuRequest: 25 
    cpuLimit: 25 
    memoryAllocation: 110Gi
    additionalProperties: |
      http-server.https.enabled=true
      http-server.https.port=8443
      http-server.https.keystore.path=/jks/docker.cluster.jks
      http-server.https.keystore.key=xxxxxxxxxxx
      http-server.authentication.type=PASSWORD
```

Comment: Hi, I have followed the same steps mentioned by you. But still getting the same issue. Updated my question with the steps that I tried. Thanks

Comment: Do the pods come up correctly? You can enter the coordinator pod by doing a: kubectl exec -it <coordinator pod> bash - then do a ls /jks and see if your jks file is there. I would also just start with the https server and not the internal communcation. In fact, that is pretty much overkill to have encryption on between pods.

Comment: Hi, I have checked the coordinator pod and I dont see /jks volume...not sure what am missing...Followed the same approach as mentioned above. Do we have to add the additional volume mentioned above into each container? Thanks